# How are Android's native libraries protected against tampering?

Tags: android, integrity

On Android it is possible to add native libraries provided by the system (/system/lib/) or the vendor (/vendor/lib/) to a system app. For example, the libandroid_runtime.so is loaded with System.load("/system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so"). How are these libraries protected against tampering? Are all libraries signed and if so, where does the system stores the public key to check the signatures and when does it check the signature (at loading/ at runtime)? Does an app needs to check the integrity when loading such a native library?

Comment: hm, Android simply has file permissions. You can't overwrite these, end of story. If you are root on your device, you can, also you can do anything else, so also end of story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android native libraries are protected under integrity of android partitions. Android uses [`dm-verity`](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/dm-verity#implementation) to verify integrity of each partition. Except `/boot` partition, other partitions contain signed hashtree which is verified by `/boot/verity_key`. The root hash and salt of hashtree and hash of boot image are stored in vbmeta partition. This vbmeta partition is signed by OEM's private key and verified by OEM public key embedded in bootloader.

Comment: Does this mean that only on boot time the integrity of the system partition is checked by dm-verity?

Comment: @Me7e0r Yes. Android Verified Boot makes use of dm-verity.